# What's with the mess of Windows Azure Storage tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Just had a question that was tagged with both [azure](/questions/tagged/azure) and [blobs](/questions/tagged/blobs) and I was pretty sure that "blobs" was not a good tag for the Azure Blobs storage service. So I did investigating and there is just a **mess** of tags for this:

[windows-azure-storage](/questions/tagged/windows-azure-storage) seems to be the primary tag for Azure storage, which seems to be broken down into separate tags [azure-storage-tables](/questions/tagged/azure-storage-tables) `<-->` [azure-table-storage](/questions/tagged/azure-table-storage) `<-->` [azure-tables](/questions/tagged/azure-tables) and [azure-storage-blobs](/questions/tagged/azure-storage-blobs). There's also the [azure-storage](/questions/tagged/azure-storage) tag, which I believe *should* be the main one in order to match the other tags that separate it (even though it only has 7 questions compared to the main one).

And other things like [azure-diagnostics](/questions/tagged/azure-diagnostics) `<-->` [windows-azure-diagnostics](/questions/tagged/windows-azure-diagnostics)...

I'm sure I probably missed something in there.

---

Also, side note: [blob](/questions/tagged/blob) and [blobs](/questions/tagged/blobs) need to be merged.